# How to create Symbolic Link to local Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift Package Xcode project that I'm making some changes to and I want to add a symlink from my App to that project so I can test it out while changing it. Can I link my app like that (just for testing) or would I need to always push a new version to GitHub?

Comment: I think [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/editing_a_package_dependency_as_a_local_package) from Apple could be of help.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's exactly what I need. Thank you :)